# Plivo recording query

Tags: php, voip, freeswitch, plivo

I am using xml api for recording call. I am using following code.

```
<Record action="http://127.0.0.1:80/plivo_recordings" maxLength="30" finishOnKey="*"/>
```

Then what should be in plivo_recordings folder.

Answer (score 1):

Your action URL is the URL that plivo will call back once your recording is ready. Plivo will hit your URL with parameters like RecordUrl to access the recorded file and other info such as RecordDuration.

The URL needs to be accessible by Plivo so 127.0.0.1 is not appropriate. It should be something like

```
<Record action="http://yourdomain.com/plivo_recordings" maxLength="30" finishOnKey="*"/>
```